# Fetch data from Azure SQL, process and store in another DB on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, migration

I am trying to find a one script solution to fetch azure data from SQL Server, preprocess it, if possible run (copy SQL Server table) as well as create new tables/or alter, to another SQL Server on Azure.

I need a utility which is programmatically accessable and can handle T-SQL as well as big data.

I am ready to do some custom stuff, if it is required to achieve. Any tips to explore would be also helpful.

Comment: break up your logic into sequence of steps  and implement each step,as of know this question is very broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this but none of them in single script as you mentioned.

First way is to create azure data factory copy activity and create linked source and corresponding destination as azure db and run using slicing. This is straight forward and programatical way. Also it is charged as per data ingestion rate.

Second way is to create SSIS source as azure db and destination as well in azure db but disadvantage is to run this ssis in some server it can be an azure vm or on premise server.

There are other ways to implement this as well...

Comment: great! For the second option, can i use that ssis package installed on one of my application server(or localhost), fetch the data (do whatever i want), and forward the script azure destination? I know, this is time taking, but it is closer to what i am looking. Any other options you can suggest, i would love to explore. First one is good,but not free.